# Vertical alignment of nested row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to vertically center an row that is nested in a row but not sure how to do this. I tried adding the vertical-align to the nested row but it does not work. It looks like the nested row is not expanding to the full height of the parent row.  Not sure how to make that row expand to the parent width. I am using bootstrap.

```css
.home{
 background: url("./../assets/covers/home.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
 background-size:     100% 100%;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;              /* optional, center the image */
 background-color: #fff;
 min-height: 1000px;
 max-height: 2832px;

}
.header{
 background:rgba(7,14,2,0.85);
 color: #fff;

 vertical-align: middle;
}
.header h1{
 font-size: 80pt;
 padding: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
 line-height: 60%;
}
.header h2{
 font-size: 23pt;
 padding:0 0 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid clearfix" >

            <section class="" id="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 home ">
                        <div class="row vertical-align">
                            <div class="col-md-5 header text-center col-centered ">
                                <h1>test</h1>
                                <h2>test</h2>                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="" id="mission">

            </section>

            <section class="" id="care">

            </section>

            <section class="" id="procedures">

            </section>

            <section class="" id="help">

            </section>

            <section class="" id="location">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="colum-md-6 gap-none">
                        <!-- <img class="bgwidth" src="./assets/covers/hands.jpg"> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want the big "TEST" to be centered?

Comment: I want the header the whole group  to be centered both horizontal and vertically. I have it centered horizontally just not vertically.

Comment: You want the dark gray container to be centered over the image or the view port?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for this? Hard to tell. http://jsfiddle.net/mm6ck3dc/6/

```
.header{
  background:rgba(7,14,2,0.85);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: It is but I do not want the background to go accross the whole width.

Comment: Ok so where do you want the image to go? You have the image size set to 100% 100%, I did not change that. if you do not want it 100% then why not change it?

Comment: I want it like this the image is the background and I want it to scale to the screen size. The box I want like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa9xyvbrirt48g9/ex.png?dl=0

Comment: Maybe you should modify your question then, I am done wasting my time... Good luck with that.